# Why isn't my webapp's welcome file being found?

Tags: struts2

My first page to be called for the Struts application should be a simple helloWorld.jsp page. This is specified in the web.xml like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>helloWorld.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

But Im getting an HTTP 404 error. What would be the correct struts.xml structure for this? Is one actually needed for the default page to be called? If not then why am I getting the error? Yes the jsp file is located in the WEB-INF folder

Thanks

**EDIT**

Added screenshot displaying location of JSP file:

[image: screeenshot of JSP location]

Comment: where is the JSP located in your webapp?  What URL are you using to hit it?

Comment: it's should be there in webapp folder.

Comment: I created my project as a Dynamic Web Project, not through Maven therefore no webapp folder gets created right? So should I create one and add the .jsp file to it

Comment: Let's just talk about where the file is in the WAR file that you end up with?  Can you look at the war file?

Comment: i ll be honest and say I don't know how to look at it and don't know where it's suppose to be P.S. is struts as difficult as Im making it out or am I just being stupid lol?

Comment: Uh . . . if you don't know how to find your WAR file, I'd say it's your newbieness that is the source of troubles ;)  wouldn't you?

Comment: You would be well serverd by reading up on some Java Web Applicationi basics.  Search for java servlets and java web applications.

Comment: Just put your JSP file directly in WebContent folder.

Comment: @AleksandrM look at my 2nd comment

Comment: @Katana24: In your question you told it is in WEB-INF folder. So were it is? And update your question.

Comment: @AleksandrM check my edited question - screenshot

Comment: helloWorld.jsp should be outside /WEB-INF. All the files with in WEB-INF will be protected. you can't access them directly.

Comment: @Katana24: How do you deploy your application? Check that all jars are included.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Struts 2.  This jsp should be hit as a JSP of the webapp, which doesn't go through Struts 2.  Troubleshooting this amounts to verifying that your webapp was loaded by the servlet container and that you have the correcty URL to hit the webapp and then this JSP.

You should look in the servlet container logs to verify that the startup of the container went okay, and it should also report to you that your webapp was loaded, init'd and started.

Next, verify that your URL is correct.  I would assume something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myWebAppContextName/helloWorld.jsp
```

The webapp context name could be different things depending upon how you deployed and configured your webapp.  If you simply dropped the war file into a tomcat's webapps folder, it will be the name of the webapp.

Comment: This jsp should be hit as a JSP of the webapp, which doesn't go through Struts 2 -> i thought struts would intercept all requests and process them as stated in the web.xml filter mapping tag

Comment: If you mapp the struts 2 filter to all requests, as is common, it will look at each request, but if it doesn't have it's own mapping for the request's URL, it will do nothing.  As would be the case here.  Then, the JSP servlet will catch the request, but this is kind of under the covers.  You could read more about the JSP technology if you like, but in short each JSP is compiled into a servlet that then receives the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Make sure that your jsp should be there in `WebRoot` folder.**

<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

index.jsp

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=welcome.action">
```

Comment: And how is that answering the question?